# Convert multi column table to single columns with repeat pattern

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose you have a column range (table) in Excel like this:

[image]

and need to convert it to a format like this:

[image]

I have searched for VBA script like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567161/multi-row-and-multi-column-excel-spreadsheet-into-single-column-keeping-column-a) and there are several tools on the market, but cannot get it to work in desired output.

How can you do this with regular Excel formula or VBA script?

Comment: unpivot the data

Comment: What version of Excel are you using as @user10781941 recommended you can use unpivot if you are using Excel 2016 or up. See this helpful article: https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/

Comment: Using Excel 2016, UNPIVOT might be a lot easier, will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LC As Long, LR As Long, Number As Long, i As Long, j As Long, NR As Long
    Dim str As String

    'Everything included in "With Statement" refer to Sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last Column
        LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Find Las Row
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from column two to last column
        For i = 2 To LC

            'Number get the value of row 1 and column i
            Number = .Cells(1, i).Value

            'Loop from row two to last row of each i
            For j = 2 To LR

                'str get the value of row j in column 1
                str = .Cells(j, 1).Value

                    NR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                    .Cells(NR + 1, 1).Value = Number
                    .Cells(NR + 1, 2).Value = str
                    .Cells(NR + 1, 3).Value = .Cells(j, i).Value


            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: will work, but explaining why or some comments may be helpful, as well as descriptive variable names.

Comment: @Kevin - The extent that a variable's name should describe its purpose in longhand vs abbreviation or acronym is a matter of personal coding style. Many coders prefer to see more operational code per line without having to scroll right due to elongated naming conventions. Personally, I find that long-winded variable names make code hard to understand; particularly when composed from a non-EN-US standpoint. The OP has offered no code of their own nor any indication of native language. Foisting your preferred coding style on other may be considered unfriendly if not outright rude.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using it, perhaps I am a newby in VBA, but it errors on "Compile error - variable not defined". Which var is not defined then? Removing Option Explicit could be done, but that creates error on 13-types don't match although it creates the desired output along with extra rows not desired. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @J3FFK - `dim j as long` (the compiler should highlight in yellow the offending var)

Comment: Ah yes that's the one. Super, it works GREAT! Thanks

Comment: @user10781941 - I am not trying to tell anyone how to code, but I believe an answer should be more clear and some commenting and descriptive variable names would help. To each his/her own.

Comment: @Kevin you are right about the comments but, my top priority is to provide an answer as fast as i can yo help others and if someone need more clarification to provide them too.

Comment: @J3FFK to you understand my comments?are you satisfy with the answer?

Comment: @Error1004 - Thanks I wasn't trying to be an ahole, just provide a little helpful criticism. Good answer!

Comment: @Error1004; yes I (think I) understand them. You answered my questions perfectly and I now have 2 methods do solve the problem: one with you VBA script, one with unpivot function in Excel Power Query. I marked you answer as question answered. Thanks!

Comment: @J3FFK glad to help again!